# Authenticate and get token for Azure Data Catalog using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-catalog

Here I am trying to register a Data Asset from Data Lake Store in the Azure Data Catalog.
I am trying to get the authentication token for Azure Data Catalog which I will then set in header as below

```
request.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+accesstoken);
```

Code I am using to get token

```
//This method sends request and gets the reponse
public static String SetRequestAndGetResponse(HttpsURLConnection request, String payload)
{ 
    String accesstoken=null;
    ExecutorService service = null;

    Future<AuthenticationResult> FutureResult;
    AuthenticationResult result;
    AuthenticationCallback callback = null;

    //Creating the credential object for DataCatalog with Client ID and Client secret picked up from the vault

    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("client_ID", "client_secret");

    try
    {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/tenant_ID/oauth2/token",true,service);

        /* 
         * getting the authentication result object using the App ID URI from Azure AD as suggested in
         * 
         * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code
         */

        FutureResult = context.acquireToken("App ID URI from Azure AD/login/aad", credential,null);
        while(!(FutureResult.isDone()))
        {}
        accesstoken=FutureResult.get().getAccessToken();
        //System.out.println("result "+accesstoken);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println("ex "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();}
```

But , I am getting exception as shown below

ex com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException:
{"error_description":"AADSTS50001: The application named https://abc.onmicrosoft.com/somecode/login/aad was not found in the tenant named tenant_id.
This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.
You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Trace ID: some_id

Correlation ID: some_id

Timestamp: 2017-04-06 09:57:01Z","error":"invalid_resource"}

at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:107)

at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:816)

at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:64)

at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:172)

at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:161)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

***************** EDIT *******************
Thanks! But, I tried with "https://graph.windows.net" as resource URI to get token using authentication context but still server responds as unauthorized request.
By the way, I am using below snippet to create a request object.

```
String fullUri = String.format("https://api.azuredatacatalog.com/catalogs/"+catalogName+"/views/tables?api-version=2016-03-30");
    URL url = null;
    try {
        //sETTING UP url connection to azure data catalog api 
        url = new URL(fullUri);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception");
    }
    HttpsURLConnection request;
    try {
        request = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
```

Please help me on how do I get this fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [`AuthenticationContext.acquireToken`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationContext.java#L229) method should be the graph resource instead of your App ID URI from Azure AD.

Please change the line of code as below:

```
FutureResult = context.acquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential, null);
```

For more info, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java

Comment: Thanks! But, I tried with that but still server responds as unauthorized request. I have added more details about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should use:

```
string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
```

Also, the resource string being passed in to the `AcquireToken` method should be "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com".